# iOS, replace an image with a downloaded one

Tags: ios

My app will be released with the images inside it, but I may need to download other images later and replace the old images with the downloaded ones.

So the question is, Is it possible to replace the images bundled inside the app with the downloaded ones??

If yes, may you recommend some resources to search in?
If no, may you suggest other way to do the previous?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the images in your bundle only as a default. You can create your own version of `[UIImage imageNamed:]` method, e.g. `[UIImage myImageNamed:]` which will look first into the folder with downloaded images and if it doesn't find the image there, it will use the one in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot programmatically change your files in the MainBundle.
However you can take the help of a database , and change the database contents dynamically.
You can save images into database using "blob".

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is either copy or link the images in the bundle to 'Application Support' in your app, mark them so no iCloud backup, then use them or their replacements. If you use a folder then if it does not exist you know it's the first launch - or just test for one image.